# Error - Expected ';' while running Gatling using sbt

Tags: sbt

I am running a Gatling test script using Jenkins on a Unix machine. The test and the Simulation passes successfully after which I am seeing the below error marked in bold below also causing the Jenkins build to fail.

**Log from the Jenkins build**

> Reports generated in 0s.
> Please open the following file:
>  >/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/gatling_test_job/target/gatling/demoscript-20200930173820423/index.html
> [info] Simulation DemoScript successful.
> [info] Simulation(s) execution ended.
> [success] Total time: 326 s (05:26), completed Sep 30, 2020 5:43:32 PM
> **>[error] Expected ';'
>
> [error] com.test.performance.DemoScript
>
> [error]**                               ^
> Build step 'Build using sbt' changed build result to FAILURE
> Build step 'Build using sbt' marked build as failure

I am using build using sbt block in my Jenkins job to trigger the test using the below command

> gatling:testOnly com.test.performance.DemoScript

Scala Version is - 2.12.10
Gatling and related libraries - 3.3.1

**Build using sbt config in Jenkins**

[image]

**sbt installation in global tool configuration**

[image]

Comment: What does com.test.performance.DemoScript look like? Was it working before?

Comment: The test as such works fine with no requests failing. It is only This - Expected ; error which comes in the end. Moreover, this does not come when running locally on Windows using Intellij with sbt command

Comment: Your issue is actually not related to Gatling. It's about sbt and passing a proper command. You should provide the full actual sbt command so that people can help you.

Comment: added further details on how I am running the test using sbt